# How can I replace a single character of a URL from a string that contains many such characters in Swift 3?

Tags: swift

So I have an image URL:

```
https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1410762334m/135625.jpg
```

And I want to change the letter **"m"** after the first block of numbers (1410762334) with the letter **"l"**.

I tried using `replacingOccurrences(of: "m", with: "l", options: .literal, range: nil)` and as expected, it replaces all m's with l's and it doesn't work. I know it's got to do with the range but I'm not sure what to put as the range. Please enlighten me :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NSRegularExpression` for this.

- Firstly, this code searches for a numeric value followed by the letter `m` and a slash (`/`).
- After that, it searches for `m` in only that range and replaces it with an `l`.

---

```
let urlString: NSString = "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1410762334m/135625.jpg"

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]m/", options: .caseInsensitive)

    let fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)
    let matchRange = regex.rangeOfFirstMatch(in: urlString as String, options: [], range: fullRange)

    let modString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "m", with: "l", options: .caseInsensitive, range: matchRange)
} catch let error {
    //NSRegularExpression threw an error; handle it properly
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
let urlString = "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1410762334m/135625.jpg"

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]m/", options: .caseInsensitive)

    let fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, urlString.count)
    let matchRange = regex.rangeOfFirstMatch(in: urlString, options: [], range: fullRange)

    let modString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "m", with: "l", options: .caseInsensitive, range: Range(matchRange, in: urlString))
} catch let error {
    //NSRegularExpression threw an error; handle it properly
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code but the line of modString is giving me an error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(NSRange, in: String)' "

Comment: @acoustickat Updated my answer to include Swift 3 code.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I'm going to assume that the number part before the `m` is the only dynamic part of the URL.

```
import Foundation

let url = "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1410762334m/135625.jpg"

if let range = url.range(of: "^https://images.gr-assets.com/books/[0-9]*", options: .regularExpression) {
  let changedUrl = "\(url[range])l/135625.jpg"
}
```